# Right aligning signature

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

I work in `\documentclass[a4paper]{book}`.

At the end of my introduction, I want to put my name and the date right aligned. It should look like this:

> *John Doe 
>
> May, 2021*

but then aligned completely on the right margin instead on the left. Note the use of cursive.

I tried:

```
\begin{rightflush}

\textit{John Doe \newline May, 2021}

\end{rightflush}
```

but this does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is called `flushright` not `rightflush`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    
    \lipsum[1]
            \begin{flushright}
                \textit{John Doe}   \\  
                \textit{May, 2021}
            \end{flushright} 

\end{document}
```

[image]